# node.js, TS - middlware does not worging

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, middleware, joi

I am trying to implement a validation middleware using routing-controllers with TypeScript and Joi for request validation. However, the middleware doesn't seem to be working as expected, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's my setup: I have a validationMiddleware function that takes a Joi.Schema as input and should validate the request body against the schema.

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import Joi from "joi";

type MiddlewareFunction = (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => void;

function validationMiddleware(schema: Joi.Schema): MiddlewareFunction {
  return (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const { error } = schema.validate(req.body);
    console.log(error);
    if (error) {
      console.log("Validation error:", error);
      return res.status(400).json({ message: error.details[0].message });
    }
    next();
    return;
  };
}

export default validationMiddleware;
```

In my controller, I'm using the middleware with the @UseBefore decorator to validate the request body before processing the request.

```
import {
  JsonController,
  Body,
  Res,
  Post,
  UseBefore,
} from "routing-controllers";
import AuthService from "./auth.services";
import { IRegister } from "./auth.types";
import validationMiddleware from "middlewares/validation.middlewares";
import { registerSchema } from "models/users.model";

@JsonController("/auth")
export default class AuthController {
  public authService = new AuthService();

  @Post("/register")
  @UseBefore(validationMiddleware(registerSchema))
  async register(@Body() body: IRegister, @Res() res: any) {
    try {
      const result = await this.authService.registerUser(body);
      if (typeof result === "string") {
        return res.status(409).send(result);
      } else if (typeof result === "object") {
        console.log(result);
        return res.status(200).send(result);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

[https://github.com/SunAndrea/bot-back-end](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.